The site tends to attract two different fields of profession
When I look at the site for now, I generally distinguish two different topics:

Questions about computer software, websites, etc., e.g.: Get used jQuery plugins from website
Questions about really low-level things, like microcontrollers, e.g.: Get code from protected PIC

Is this a problem? I feel like it might get a problem, because there aren't that much people who are working in both fields. While the way of working may be the same, we might get two subsets (one for high-level and one for low-level) in the community, that aren't really communicating with each other.
If this is a problem, how are we going to resolve this? We could of course change the FAQ to accept only one type. We could say the second type has to go to Electrical Engineering, for example. However, there might be a neater solution with which we aren't losing a part of the community. 

That's the whole point of the site: being about reverse engineering of anything. If we start splitting, then software reverse engineering goes on Stack Overflow, hardware reverse engineering goes on Electrical Engineering, chemical reverse engineering goes on Chemistry, and so on, and this site needn't exist.

And you don't feel we're going to get a problem with several subsets in the community? Why not? Are you arguing that there are no subsets because we all have RE in common?

@CamilStaps Yes, we all have RE in common. Again, that's the whole point of the site.
